# How to load a Docker image from a tar file

Tags: windows, docker, hortonworks-sandbox

I have installed Docker for Windows. I have downloaded `HDP_2.5_docker.tar` from http://hortonworks.com/downloads/#sandbox which is a 10 GB file.

How can I load an image tar file? I have tried this command:

```
docker import HDP_2.5_docker.tar
```

Answer (score 131, accepted):

You can use [`docker load`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/load/)

```
Usage:  docker load [OPTIONS]

Load an image from a tar archive or STDIN
```

### **Git bash console:**

```
docker load < HDP_2.5_docker.tar
```

### **Windows cmd:**

```
docker load -i windowsservercore.tar
```

Comment: thnx, but i m getting `The system cannot find the file specified`.

Comment: @Naveen you need to run this command in folder where `HDP_2.5_docker` is located (or use path for `HDP_2.5_docker` file). Also check whether file extension is not `tar.gz` by default the name of downloaded file should be `HDP_2.5_docker.tar.gz`

Comment: This doesn't work for me in cmd.exe env: `docker.exe load < windowsservercore.tar`, returns `requested load from stdin, but stdin is empty`. The following one works though: `docker.exe load -i windowsservercore.tar`. I think the answer is incorrect (question is marked with "windows") and should be fixed.

Comment: @alexkasko Thanks for comment! You are probably right cause I dont use cmd but "git bash" console. I added your point to answer to make it more visible for others.

Comment: I may be late here but it might help someone.. for windows platform its `-i` flag!

Comment: Or just use `docker load -i <file>` in both Windows and Linux (bash)...

Answer (score 25):

Firstly, put the tar file under your user folder: i.e: `C:\Users\yourName\xxx.tar`

Secondly, run the Docker load CMD:

```
docker load -i xxx.tar
```

After it is done, we could see the file is loaded as Docker images by running CMD:

```
docker images
```

Comment: The accepted answer from VladoDemcak gave me the error `requested load from stdin, but stdin is empty`, but this method worked. Thanks

Comment: Thank you, that is the correct location to place a docker image.

Answer (score 16):

you can do:

```sh
docker image import file.tar images_name:image_tag
```

Comment: I tried this way since I wanted to provide a docker image name and tag name but when I tried to run the docker image it was throwing an error. Whereas using `docker load` worked fine when running the docker image.

Answer (score 14):

Load the desired docker file, assuming you are in the same directory as the tar file, you can use -

```sh
$ docker load -i filename.tar
```

On successful import, you will see a success message along with the image ID

Check in the docker images for the image ID that you just received:

```sh
docker images
```

You will see the docker loaded successfully in the docker images list. However, there is one thing worth mentioning in case you might get confused; the date reflected in the command output might reflect the date when docker is created. Assuming, docker got created 5 days ago then the same will be shown in the output. Better way to confirm if your docker is loaded or not is to check for the image ID or repo and tag name (if you know).

You can finally run the docker using the command -

```sh
$ docker run -it image-ID
```